# Is my SQLite Database created anew each time I start the application?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app that Im working on and I wonder what happens to my Database when I close my application and start it again, because I never specify what happens on onPause, onResume and onDestroy (because I dont know what to specify there).

Here is my DBTools class

```
public class DBTools extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBTools(Context applicationcontext) {
        super(applicationcontext, "rggarb.db", null, 1);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

        String tableUsers = "CREATE TABLE users ( userId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, userName TEXT, userEmail TEXT, userPassword TEXT, userAvatar TEXT, userSex TEXT)";
        database.execSQL(tableUsers);

    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
        String dropTableUsers = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableUsers";
        database.execSQL(dropTableUsers);
        onCreate(database);
    }
             //some CRUD methods here, irrelevant for this question

}
```

and here is how I operate with it

in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    DBTools dbTools = new DBTools(this);
```

then the user goes to Signup activity, and there:

public class Signup extends Activity  {

```
private DBTools dbTools = new DBTools(this);
    //later on in this class I do some checks and inserts.
```

I suspect something might be wrong and Im not familiar with the lifecycle of the DB the way Im using it. Does it go blank on each onDestroy? do I need to instantiate it in MainActivity every time? if I have instantiated it there, do I need to instatiate it yet again in Signup Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, no. Once the application has created the database, that database is saved and it's data persists through application shutdown and other lifecycle activities.

If you programmatically insert/create database entries, then you only have to do those once. Otherwise, you'll have recurring data.

Not unless you write a code to destroy the DB then no, the database will be there.

So, to answer your questions..

`Does it go blank on each onDestroy?`

No, once you've inserted entries, they will be there forever. Otherwise, SQLite wouldn't be recommended for data persistence.

`Do I need to instantiate it in MainActivity every time?`

I usually create a global instance of my db helper in my activities so if I need to run a query, I'll just call that instance and do the query.

`If I have instantiated it there, do I need to instatiate it yet again in Signup Activity?`

You really don't "instantiate" the database all over again as once you create it, it's in your application. Creating an instance of your db helper in your Signup Activity would just enable that activity to run queries.

Comment: Yes. Reinstalling the app would wipe the db data.

Comment: if I have instantiated it in MainActivity, do I need to instatiate it yet again in Signup Activity?

Comment: If you plan on inserting data in your Signup Activity, then yes. But if you won't do any db operations in your Signup Activity, then no need. Instantiating your db in your MainActivity creates the db for the app to use. Meaning that all activities will be able to use that db.

Comment: If you use adb reinstall option, it won't remove DB. DB is removed only if you manually uninstall and then install application again.

Answer (score 2):

DB will only be re-created if database version is changed (passed in super constructor call) or application is uninstalled.

If DB version is changed, impact is dependent upon your implementation in onUpgrade()